# Entity Framework error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker. При сохранении

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(RegisterApplicationForm doc)
{
    var entity = new sovadb001Entities0();
    order norder = new order();
    if(doc.fileNames!=null)
    foreach (var fileName in doc.fileNames)
    {
        //string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(UploadedFile.FileName);
        document ndoc = new document();
        ndoc.conuntOfSymbols = 1;
        System.IO.FileInfo fi =  new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Temporary/" + fileName));
        ndoc.dataType =fi.Extension;
        ndoc.pathToDoc = fi.Directory.FullName;
        ndoc.order = norder;
        ndoc.idOrder = norder.IdOrder;
        //DataBase.AddDoc(ndoc);
        entity.documents.Add(ndoc);
        norder.documents.Add(ndoc);
        Server.MapPath("~/Content/file" + fileName).ToString();
        System.IO.File.Move(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Temporary/" + fileName), Server.MapPath("~/Content/file/"+fileName));
        //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("~/Content/Temporary/" + fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
        //    using(FileStream fsw=new FileStream("~/Content/file/"+fileName,FileMode.CreateNew)){
        //    ;
        //    fs
        //    }
        //}
    }
    foreach (var spec in doc.spec)
    {
        documentSpecialization ndocSpec = new documentSpecialization();
        ndocSpec.order = norder;
        ndocSpec.IdOrder = norder.IdOrder;
        ndocSpec.IdSpecialization = DataBase.GetSpecialization(spec).IdSpecialization;
        ndocSpec.specialization = DataBase.GetSpecialization(spec);
        //DataBase.AddDocSpec(ndocSpec);

        entity.documentSpecializations.Add(ndocSpec);
        norder.documentSpecializations.Add(ndocSpec);
    }
    norder.dateOfCompletion = DateTime.Now;
    norder.name = doc.name;
    norder.description = doc.description;

    norder.idDone = false;
    //DataBase.AddApplication(norder);

    entity.orders.Add(norder);
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    // }
}'
```

Ошибка возникает в методе `entity.documentSpecializations.Add(ndocSpec);`

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException не обработано пользовательским кодом
>     HResult=-2147024894
>     Message=Файл 'C:\Users\Олександр\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SovaTranslate_001\SovaTranslate_001\Content\Temporary\1O45e0euv0o.jpg' не найден.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     FileName=C:\Users\Олександр\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SovaTranslate_001\SovaTranslate_001\Content\Temporary\1O45e0euv0o.jpg
>     StackTrace:
>          в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>          в System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
>          в System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
>          в SovaTranslate_001.Controllers.ApplicationController.Save(RegisterApplicationForm doc) в c:\Users\Олександр\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SovaTranslate_001\SovaTranslate_001\Controllers\ApplicationController.cs:строка 76
>          в lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          в System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>          в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>     InnerException:

Comment: Ясно сформулируйте ваш вопрос. Приведите stack trace.

Comment: Поставьте  ваш код в `tyr{} catch{}` блок, потом публикуйте ошибку.

Comment: Зачем, если ошибка будет та же, просто програма будет работать дальше.

Comment: В ошибке явн сказано, что файл в `Content\Temporary\`, который вы пытаетесь переместить, не существует.  EF и большая часть кода в вопросе к ошибке отношения не имеет - ищите проблему в той части кода, которая этот файл должна создавать.